# React-Native/Expo/Cygwin “Unexpected Token” Problem

Tags: powershell, react-native, cygwin, expo

After installing react-devtools, I am no longer able to run expo-cli.
Everything was working fine until I did that. I’m now getting the error below.
My Powershell permissions were also changed to "restricted". I've restored my registry to the previous day and have uninstalled/reinstalled node and yarn in an effort to fix this.

The error lists Cygwin, which I don't have installed on my computer (does not show up in a registry search), however, searching my computer, I see that Cygwin was installed with Git:

C:\Program Files\Git\usr\share\cygwin
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\cygwin-console-helper.exe
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\lldb\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\lib\perlS\core_per|\File\Spec\cygwin.pm
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\share\cygwin\cygwin.ldif
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\share\tern1info\63\cygwin
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\lib\terminf0\63\cygwin

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.
Windows 10
npm: 6.6.0
node: v10.15.0
yarn: v1.13.0

```
expo start --android
At C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\expo.ps1:5 char:13
+     *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
+             ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\expo.ps1:8 char:3
+ if [ -x "$basedir/pwsh" ]; then
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\expo.ps1:8 char:5
+ if [ -x "$basedir/pwsh" ]; then
+     ~
Missing type name after '['.
At C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\expo.ps1:9 char:20
+ ... edir/pwsh"  "$basedir/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/expo.ps1" "$@" ...
+   
Unexpected token '"$basedir/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/expo.ps1"' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\expo.ps1:9 char:73
+ ... edir/pwsh"  "$basedir/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/expo.ps1" "$@"
+   
Unexpected token '"$@"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

@supermerio

**C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\expo.ps1**

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/pwsh" ]; then
  "$basedir/pwsh"  "$basedir/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/expo.ps1" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  pwsh  "$basedir/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/expo.ps1" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Also, I was able to get expo working by installing it into my repo and calling it from there.
I noticed a difference in the local script vs the script in the global install. The local script calls “node” where the global script (above) calls “pwsh”.

**\LactFacts\lactfact_190118\node_modules.bin\expo:**

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../expo-cli/bin/expo.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../expo-cli/bin/expo.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Yarn `1.13.0` issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6902#issuecomment-453534280

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever is in "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\expo.ps1" has a badly formatted if statement.

Are you able to review that file to confirm? Post here if possible.

Comment: Can't format comments, so I posted in OP above. Thanks.

Comment: The code in expo.ps1 isn't powershell, although appears that it is trying to be interpreted as such.